# How to get COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO from COR_PRF_ELT_INFO using GetFunctionEnter3Info function in ICorProfilerInfo3 interface

Tags: clr-profiling-api

I'm using CLR profiling API and trying to get arguments info (COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO) from COR_PRF_ELT_INFO using GetFunctionEnter3Info function.

Below is my code. It seems GetFunctionEnter3Info function is not setting the value for pArgumentInfo. It always has null value. However, the function returns S_OK, which is a success.

I may be missing something. How should I get COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO from COR_PRF_ELT_INFO ?

```
    PROFILER_STUB EnterStub(FunctionIDOrClientID functionId, COR_PRF_ELT_INFO eltInfo)
{
        COR_PRF_FRAME_INFO *pFrameInfo = 0;
        ULONG *pcbArgumentInfo = 0;
        COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO *pArgumentInfo = NULL;

        corProfilerInfo->GetFunctionEnter3Info(functionId.functionID, eltInfo, pFrameInfo, pcbArgumentInfo, pArgumentInfo);
        if(pArgumentInfo) {
            //
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you include [`COR_PRF_ENABLE_FUNCTION_ARGS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/cor-prf-monitor-enumeration#feature-enabling-flags) in your call to `SetEventMask`?

Comment: yes I did. I enabled the following flags : COR_PRF_MONITOR_ENTERLEAVE,COR_PRF_ENABLE_FUNCTION_ARGS,COR_PRF_ENABLE_FUNCTION_RETVAL,COR_PRF_ENABLE_FRAME_INFO

Comment: Is the method by any chance in an ngen-ed image? (eg mscorlib). I noticed you didn't include `COR_PRF_DISABLE_ALL_NGEN_IMAGES` to disable ngen-ed images or `COR_PRF_USE_PROFILE_IMAGES` to request images that were ngen-ed with profiling support.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit tricky,

[By msdn doc:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilerinfo3-getfunctionenter3info-method)

> pcbArgumentInfo
>   [in, out] A pointer to the total size, in bytes, of the COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO structure (plus any additional COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_RANGE structures for the argument ranges pointed to by pArgumentInfo). If the specified size is not enough, ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER is returned and the expected size is stored in pcbArgumentInfo. To call GetFunctionEnter3Info just to retrieve the expected value for *pcbArgumentInfo, set *pcbArgumentInfo=0 and pArgumentInfo=NULL

In other words, you have a single `COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO` structure, which references multiple `COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_RANGE`.
First of all, get a number of bytes of `pcbArgumentInfo`, after that allocate bytes and pass the pointer to `GetFunctionEnter3Info` as `COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO`.

Here is an example

```
PROFILER_STUB EnterStub(FunctionIDOrClientID functionId, COR_PRF_ELT_INFO eltInfo)
{
    ULONG pcbArgumentInfo = 0;
    COR_PRF_FRAME_INFO frameInfo;
    corProfilerInfo3->GetFunctionEnter3Info(functionIDOrClientID.functionID, eltInfo, &frameInfo, &pcbArgumentInfo, NULL);

    char* pArgumentInfo = new char[pcbArgumentInfo];
    corProfilerInfo3->GetFunctionEnter3Info(functionIDOrClientID.functionID, eltInfo, &frameInfo, &pcbArgumentInfo, (COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO*)pArgumentInfo);

    COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO* ptr = (COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_INFO*)pArgumentInfo;
}
```

To access the second `argument info` block of `COR_PRF_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT_RANGE` use

```
prt->ranges[1]
```

The number of blocks is written in `ptr->numRanges`